# url of child theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a website in wordpress, for this I take a theme and create a child theme.

I copy in the folder of the child a style.css  and header.php, because I want to modify the header too. I modify the file of the child.

In my style.css I add the line Template: with the name of the father theme

```
/*
Theme Name: Example
Theme URI: http://www.woothemes.com/
Version: 1.2.15
Description: Designed by <a href="http://www.woothemes.com">WooThemes</a>.
Author: WooThemes
Author URI: http://www.woothemes.com
Tags: woothemes
Template: mystile

  Copyright: (c) 2009-2011 WooThemes.
  License: GNU General Public License v2.0
  License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

*/
```

I am using this line in the header.php

```
<?php $logo = esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . 'images/logo.png' ); ?>
```

of my child theme to take a images but this line return the url of the father theme no his child!

I take this.

```
http://localhost/.../wp-content/themes/mystile/images/...
```

I I want this

```
http://localhost/.../wp-content/themes/example/images...
```

any idea

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), this function checks first in the child  theme directory and then in the parent's. The one you're using only checks in the parent directory.

Bottom line: if a function doesn't behave as you expect, check the Codex. Much probably you'll find out why over there.

Comment: brasofolio is right, see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri

Answer (score -2):

Add to `functions.php`:

```
// create a URL to the child theme
function get_template_directory_child() {
    $directory_template = get_template_directory_uri(); 
    $directory_child = str_replace('storefront', '', $directory_template) . 'child-storefront';

    return $directory_child;
}
```