# How to get child theme url in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a child theme in WordPress. I have uploaded the assets folder that contains css and javascripts. It will be a custom theme.

Inside the  tag i have included the the css file to get the css file.

**There is a problem in my current code below:**

```
<link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The code below will work if it is without the styles.css after icomoon folder.

```
<link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/css/icons/icomoon" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I want the it to output as:
//child_theme_url/assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css

I want the styles.css at the end of the include file.

Please help.

Comment: Please check  [http://stackoverflow.com/a/18724137/1719246](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18724137/1719246)

Comment: @softsdev Pls flag as a duplicate rather than linking to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [url of child theme in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724007/url-of-child-theme-in-wordpress)

Comment: checkout this link . i think it will help you https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this hook function in  your child theme `function.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css' );

}
```

Note: `get_template_directory_uri()`  instead of  `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

Answer (score 4):

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` *will* return the child theme directory url, you got that bit just right. (`get_template_directory_uri()` would return the parent theme directory url.)

Also, if you want `styles.css` outputted, the first line of code will do that. Can't see what could be wrong with it. That means something else is likely not working as intended. Are you sure it shouldn't be `style.css`, for example? Anyway, such an issue would have nothing to do with WordPress correctly returning the child theme url or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

to put at the end theme-child/style.css, you write the function (in functions.php):

```
function sp_enqueue_stylesheets() {
    wp_register_style( 'style-sp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-sp' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sp_enqueue_stylesheets', 9999 );
```

Thi is the lastest CSS in the header ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use following code for child theme directory.

```
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>
```

Comment: Echoes it instead of just returning the value.