# Wordpress Child Theme why cannot load logo

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to change the default logo to custom logo in a child theme. The problem is, it can only read an image file from the parent directory and failed to load the image if I try to load an image file which is located in the child theme.

The image file name is: `"twitter_header_photo_2.png"`

Below is the coding in `header.php`:

```
<h1 itemprop="name">
    <a itemprop="url" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>">
        <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'logo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/twitter_header_photo_2.png' ) ): ?>
             <img itemprop="logo" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'logo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/twitter_header_photo_2.png' ) ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>"/>
            <?php else: ?>
        <?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

When I put the image file namely `"twitter_header_photo_2.png"` under images folder at parent theme folder, it will show on the Header as what I want. But when I put this image file from parent theme to child theme, it cannot work.

Additional Information:

1. There has no header option to upload header image in appearance menu at this theme.
2. I had changed the "get_template_directory_uri()" to "get_stylesheet_directory_uri()", still cannot work as expected.

Working environment: `XAMPP`, `Wordpress 5.0.1`

Comment: Please see this solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104349/how-to-insert-a-logo-in-the-header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [url of child theme in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724007/url-of-child-theme-in-wordpress)

Comment: Basically `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the uri of the parent theme, and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns the uri of childthemes

Comment: The problem is solved by referring to all the information and replies above. I change the "get_template_directory_uri()" to "get_stylesheet_directory_uri()" in header.php and also functions.php, and then adjust the width and height. it works now. Thank you.